# How to run Amplify's uploadFile function within a dart isolate?

Tags: flutter, dart, aws-amplify, dart-isolates

My application has a function that allows to upload videos and other large files to Amazon S3 buckets via Amplify storage. The below function works as expected and uploads a file to my S3 bucket:

```
  Future<String> uploadFile({File? file, String path = "", String fileName = "", String fileExtension = ""}) async {
try {
  final key = path+fileName+'.'+fileExtension;
  final result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    local: file!,
    key: key,
  );
  return result.key;
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
} }
```

However, given the size of some of these files, the time required to upload can be large and I want to avoid that my users have to wait until the file is completely uploaded. Therefore I want to run the above function in a dart `Isolate`, so that the file can continue uploading while my user Navigates to different screens of the app.

I tried to achieve this with the below function:

```
  static uploadFileIsolate(List<dynamic> args) async {
try {
  SendPort responsePort = args[0];
  File file = args[1];
  String path = args[2];
  String fileName = args[3];
  String fileExtension = args[4];
  final key = path+fileName+'.'+fileExtension;

  final result = await Amplify.Storage.uploadFile(
    local: file,
    key: key,
  );
  Isolate.exit(responsePort, result);


} catch (e) {
  throw e;
} }
```

Which I call like this from my main function:

```
        final p = ReceivePort();
        Isolate.spawn(uploadFileIsolate, [p.sendPort, file, path, fileName, fileExtension]);
```

This is not working and throws the below error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_isolate.cc(1111)] Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      DatabaseService.uploadFileIsolate (package:mastory/services/database_service.dart:202:7)
#1      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:300:17)
#2      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

After reading [this issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/87) it makes me think that the error comes from the fact that Amplify is not configured in the 'isolated' environment.

So my question is: How can I make Amplify's uploadFile function work in an Isolate?

Or, if that is not possible, how can I make sure that the uploadFile function continues until completion while allowing my user to Navigate to other screens in my app?

Comment: A file upload is not computationally difficult so moving the work to it's own isolate is not beneficial. Dart is already an async language and users will be able to navigate to other pages while this uploads by default. This is the purpose of async.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is this also true when you pop the context after calling the upload method rather than using Navigator.push?

Comment: Futures are not cancellable; they will run to completion once they're started regardless of what you do (other than completely closing the app as the Dart VM will be destroyed).

Comment: Hi Christopher! Thanks for the clarification :) I made the upload function static and removed the assignment of returned confirmation and then it worked! thanks a lot